# Получить все, а не только первое совпадение как ВПР(VLOOKUP)

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Дана таблица имён и фамилий, вот ссылка:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13IyzK_Wa-AuIUG4iiXh2hD8g4orikKB-eo-vEz6qIss/edit?usp=sharing

Нужно по фамилии найти имена всех людей с такой фамилией. Найти хотя бы одного легко с помощью VLOOKUP [C1] или формулой из [B1]. Формулы из [B2], [B3], [B4] и [B5] ищут как-раз то, что нужно - они ищут 1е 2е 3е и 4ое имена соответственно. Формула почерпнута из [источника](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2699-excel-vlookup-find-first-2nd-match.html).

Помогите понять почему и как формула работает, а её составные части в столбце C не работают.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно по фамилии найти имена всех людей с такой фамилией.

Это задача фильтрации, а не поиска. И решается одной формулой:

```
=filter(B:B, A:A = "Ivanova")
```